# MarkItUp Form POST data missing

Tags: forms, post, markitup

I'm using MarkItup to turn my form textarea into a WYSIWYG editor:

http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/

The textarea is configured as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#markItUp").markItUp(mySettings);
   });
</script>
```

The textarea works well and I can format my input into HTML mark-up. However when I submit my form the POST data is not present for the textarea. If I remove the initialisation above and resubmit the textarea input is in the POST data.

I know this is a Jquery plugin which might rely on serializing the form input, but how can I POST my form without jQuery? I seems a bit short sighted and lazy to not allow this feature.

Anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is to use a proper mark up tool, TinyMCE posts the marked-up input enabling it to be processed via a regular server form submit.